# Homomorphism between $S_n$ to $\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory

Does there exist nontrivial homomorphism between symmetric group $S_n$ to set of integer $\mathbb Z$?

If yes, how many?

If not, then why?

Comment: Hint: What are the finite subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Every nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$, which is infinite. Hence the only homomorphism is the trivial one. There are however nice homomorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Comment: Can we use the same technique to find the Number of homomorphism between Dihedral group (D_n) to a set of integer(Z)

Answer (score 2):

An element of finite order is by a homomorphism always mapped to an element of finite order. This is proven quite directly from the defining properties of homomorphisms. So given an $s\in S_n$ and a homomorhism $h:S_n\to \Bbb Z$, what can $h(s)$ possibly be? Does this argument change for $D_n$ instead of $S_n$?

Answer (score 2):

Noticing that there are very few elements of finite order in $\mathbb Z$ helps. In particular, since a homomorphism sends elements of finite order to elements of finite order, and in a finite group $G$ all elements are of finite order, there is really very little freedom in what a homomorphism $G\to \mathbb Z$ can do.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi$ is a group homomorphism between two groups $G$ to $H$ , then for any $a \in G$ , $o(\phi(a)) | o(a) \ldots (*)$ . Since we are considering homomorphisms from $S_n$ to $\Bbb Z$ and $S_n$ is a finite group, any element in $S_n$ is a divisor of $n!$ and hence finite . Thus its image element must also be of finite order (due to $(*)$), but in $\Bbb Z$ , 0 is the only element of finite order, thus all the elements in $S_n$ should be mapped to 0 i.e. the trivial 0-homomorphism is the only homomorphism from $S_n$ to $\Bbb Z$ .

Note that here we are not using any special property of $S_n$ , in fact the statement is true for any finite group .

Comment: Can we use the same technique to find the number of nontrivial homomorphism between set of integer (Z) to symmetric group(S_n)

Comment: @rohinimore of course not.  And you should ask a separate question for elaborate discussions on your query.